# Create a drill-down map with leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

My goal is to create an interactive map with leaflet which will display the us states' `population`. Then when the user will click on a state the map will drill down to the counties of this state displaying the `population` of each county. Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLZLKB). In the counties dataset there are the states and the counties data that could be used to create such a map. I guess that in the state level the population should first summarized by state. But I do not know if this drill-down is possible. Your feedback is more than valuable.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(noncensus)
library(tigris)
options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)
data(counties)

counties <- counties %>%
  mutate(GEOID = paste0(state_fips, county_fips))

counties_sf <- tigris::counties() %>% 
  as("sf") %>% 
  left_join(counties, by = "GEOID")
pal <- colorQuantile("YlOrRd", domain = counties_sf$population)

m <- leaflet(counties_sf) %>%
  setView(-96, 37.8, 4) %>%
  addTiles()

m <- m %>% addPolygons(
  fillColor = ~pal(population),
  weight = 2,
  opacity = 1,
  color = "white",
  dashArray = "3",
  fillOpacity = 0.7)
m
```